# ETL on S3 : Duplicate rows : how to update old entries?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, etl, aws-glue

During my ETL imports some pre-synchronized entries are supplied multiple times by my source (because updated by the service) and therefore imported multiple times in AWS. I would like to implement a structure that overwrites an entry if it already exists (something close to a key-value store for few rows updated twice).

My requirements entails to operate on one terabyte of data and to operate on glue (or potentially redshift).

**I implemented the solution as follows:**

- I read the data from my source
- I save each entry in a different file by choosing the unique identifier of the content as the file name.
- I index my raw data with a glue crawler scanning new files on S3
- I run a glue job to transform the raw data in an OLAP compliant format (parquet).

Is this the right way to proceed?
This seems personally correct to me even if I have concerns about the large amount of separate files in my raw data (1 file per entry).

Thank you,

Hugo

Comment: While you approach is serving your purpose , one file for each row is not the right way. You will end up with very large number of file where listing of file will consume a lot of time. Also if you are planning to move the files to glacier later it will be a pain to retrieve it. If you can copy the data into Redhift and clean it that would be much easier.

Comment: This problem seems very common and yet difficult to manage on AWS. When I was checking out redshift, I saw that it was necessary to join the 2 tables, batch delete the intersection and re-import the new data. It seems tricky to me to perform an operation like this if to only add 1 MB of data in 100GB. Are you solving this problem on redshift in the same way? I would tend to think that the glue crawler would be able to detect only the new updated files in my raw data and my glue job will only process my new files to merge them into my clean-data. (Ok for  "listing of file will consume a lot..)

Comment: I do it by joining 2 tables and do a delta delete of common rows say last 15 days.. as redshift is columnar it does delete and insert without any pain.. infact I run it every 2 hours will millions of records..

Comment: Okay, many thanks :)